# Wow slider thumbnails wrapping

Tags: word-wrap, wowslider

I have used wowslider to produce a slideshow in a website and it has worked fine for years. I have been trying to add more pictures to the slideshow and they display ok, but the thumbnails are wrapping around so that I start to get a portion showing of a second row. If I remove the new images, it works fine. If I add six of the new images (out of the twenty I am trying to add) it works fine. If I add a seventh, it wraps. The thumbnail that is wrapping is the last one in the slideshow sequence.

Is there something in the script.js or the various scripts or style sheets that would cause this wrapping? I suspect that there is a container limit that is causing this, so it would be good if anyone knew what it might be and whether I can increase to include the new pictures.
Regards,
Chris

I look through the source.js and can see nothing that might limit the block container width. I am totally lost looking through the jquery.js file and also the wowslider.js. Same with the css files.